# What am I missing getting mpirun to schedule across multiple nodes?

Tags: raspberry-pi, mpi, slurm

**TL;DR;**  I'm having troubles getting MPI to schedule jobs across more than a single node. There seems to be a communication error between nodes at the MPI level that isn't a problem for TCP or at the Slurm level. Ultimately, I seem to be missing something about setting up MPI communication and I'm not sure what.

---

I'm beginning to teach myself some High Performance Computing using a cluster of Raspberry Pi's. I've followed the steps in https://glmdev.medium.com/building-a-raspberry-pi-cluster-f5f2446702e8 (All three blog posts of the series) to get a two-node cluster set up (with plans to add more later).

The trouble came when it came time to use Slurm to schedule a python MPI job (the pi calculation in the blog post). When scheduling the job as described in the blog post, I get the following message:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
An ORTE daemon has unexpectedly failed after launch and before
communicating back to mpirun. This could be caused by a number
of factors, including an inability to create a connection back
to mpirun due to a lack of common network interfaces and/or no
route found between them. Please check network connectivity
(including firewalls and network routing requirements).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After testing things out, I've confirmed that slurm works as I expected. For example:

```
pi@cluster-master:/clusterfs/calc-pi $ srun -n 6 hostname
cluster-master
cluster-master
cluster-01
cluster-01
cluster-01
cluster-01
```

Running `mpirun` works when targeting the master `mpirun --host cluster-master -n 1 hostname`, but targeting the worker `mpirun --host cluster-01 -n 1 hostname` will hang. Reducing the task count from the pi calculation example also works (and actually runs on `cluster-01`).

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=4

cd $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR

mpiexec -n 4 /clusterfs/usr/bin/python3 calculate.py
```

---

**EDIT 1**

```
pi@cluster-master:/clusterfs/calc-pi $ srun orted
[cluster-01:01960] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file ess_env_module.c at line 147
[cluster-01:01960] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad parameter in file util/session_dir.c at line 106
[cluster-01:01960] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad parameter in file util/session_dir.c at line 345
[cluster-01:01960] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad parameter in file base/ess_base_std_orted.c at line 270
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  orte_session_dir failed
  --> Returned value Bad parameter (-5) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
srun: error: cluster-01: task 0: Exited with exit code 213
```

MPI was installed via the command `srun --nodes=2 apt install openmpi-bin openmpi-common libopenmpi3 libopenmpi-dev -y`. If I'm understanding this correctly, srun will run the apt command on two nodes (which is all I have).

Adding a full path to the submission script did not change the result.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=6
cd $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR
/usr/bin/mpiexec -n 6 /clusterfs/usr/bin/python3 calculate.py
```

---

EDIT 2

Ifconfig output

```
pi@cluster-master:/clusterfs/calc-pi $ ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:f9:16:89  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3546  bytes 371661 (362.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3546  bytes 371661 (362.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.15.30.222  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.15.30.255
        inet6 fe80::10f0:f020:1af7:b503  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:f9:16:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 46530  bytes 10782530 (10.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11017  bytes 2184717 (2.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pi@cluster-01:~ $ ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:f9:15:6c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1103  bytes 77867 (76.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1103  bytes 77867 (76.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.15.30.235  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.15.30.255
        inet6 fe80::9489:150a:535d:4485  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:f9:15:6d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 92797  bytes 27212632 (25.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 60789  bytes 48894420 (46.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

**EDIT 3/4**

Running with `oob_base_verbose`. I should note that `10.15.30.222` is `cluster-master` which is where I'm running these commands. Edit 4 replaced the bad output with a now working mpirun.

```
pi@cluster-master:/clusterfs/calc-pi $ mpirun --mca oob_base_verbose 10 --host cluster-01 -n 1 hostname
[cluster-master:08881] mca: base: components_register: registering framework oob components
[cluster-master:08881] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component ud
[cluster-master:08881] mca: base: components_register: component ud register function successful
[cluster-master:08881] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component tcp
[cluster-master:08881] mca: base: components_register: component tcp register function successful
[cluster-master:08881] mca: base: components_open: opening oob components
[cluster-master:08881] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component ud
[cluster-master:08881] mca: base: components_open: component ud open function successful
[cluster-master:08881] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component tcp
[cluster-master:08881] mca: base: components_open: component tcp open function successful
[cluster-master:08881] mca:oob:select: checking available component ud
[cluster-master:08881] mca:oob:select: Querying component [ud]
[cluster-master:08881] oob:ud: component_available called
[cluster-master:08881] mca:oob:select: Skipping component [ud] - failed to startup
[cluster-master:08881] mca:oob:select: checking available component tcp
[cluster-master:08881] mca:oob:select: Querying component [tcp]
[cluster-master:08881] oob:tcp: component_available called
[cluster-master:08881] WORKING INTERFACE 1 KERNEL INDEX 1 FAMILY: V4
[cluster-master:08881] WORKING INTERFACE 2 KERNEL INDEX 3 FAMILY: V4
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] oob:tcp:init adding 10.15.30.222 to our list of V4 connections
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] TCP STARTUP
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] attempting to bind to IPv4 port 0
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] assigned IPv4 port 60821
[cluster-master:08881] mca:oob:select: Adding component to end
[cluster-master:08881] mca:oob:select: Found 1 active transports
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]: get transports
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:get transports for component tcp
[cluster-01:06357] mca: base: components_register: registering framework oob components
[cluster-01:06357] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component ud
[cluster-01:06357] mca: base: components_register: component ud register function successful
[cluster-01:06357] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component tcp
[cluster-01:06357] mca: base: components_register: component tcp register function successful
[cluster-01:06357] mca: base: components_open: opening oob components
[cluster-01:06357] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component ud
[cluster-01:06357] mca: base: components_open: component ud open function successful
[cluster-01:06357] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component tcp
[cluster-01:06357] mca: base: components_open: component tcp open function successful
[cluster-01:06357] mca:oob:select: checking available component ud
[cluster-01:06357] mca:oob:select: Querying component [ud]
[cluster-01:06357] oob:ud: component_available called
[cluster-01:06357] mca:oob:select: Skipping component [ud] - failed to startup
[cluster-01:06357] mca:oob:select: checking available component tcp
[cluster-01:06357] mca:oob:select: Querying component [tcp]
[cluster-01:06357] oob:tcp: component_available called
[cluster-01:06357] WORKING INTERFACE 1 KERNEL INDEX 1 FAMILY: V4
[cluster-01:06357] WORKING INTERFACE 2 KERNEL INDEX 3 FAMILY: V4
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:tcp:init adding 10.15.30.235 to our list of V4 connections
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] TCP STARTUP
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] attempting to bind to IPv4 port 0
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] assigned IPv4 port 35529
[cluster-01:06357] mca:oob:select: Adding component to end
[cluster-01:06357] mca:oob:select: Found 1 active transports
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]: get transports
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:get transports for component tcp
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] OOB_SEND: rml_oob_send.c:265
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:base:send to target [[63716,0],0] - attempt 0
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:base:send unknown peer [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:set_addr checking if peer [[63716,0],0] is reachable via component tcp
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:tcp: working peer [[63716,0],0] address tcp://10.15.30.222:60821
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]: peer [[63716,0],0] is reachable via component tcp
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:tcp:send_nb to peer [[63716,0],0]:10 seq = -1
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:[oob_tcp.c:204] processing send to peer [[63716,0],0]:10 seq_num = -1 via [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:[oob_tcp.c:225] queue pending to [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp:send_nb: initiating connection to [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:[oob_tcp.c:239] connect to [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] orte_tcp_peer_try_connect: attempting to connect to proc [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] orte_tcp_peer_try_connect: attempting to connect to proc [[63716,0],0] on socket 19
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] orte_tcp_peer_try_connect: attempting to connect to proc [[63716,0],0] on 10.15.30.222:60821 - 0 retries
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] waiting for connect completion to [[63716,0],0] - activating send event
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] mca_oob_tcp_listen_thread: incoming connection: (24, 0) 10.15.30.235:58444
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] connection_handler: working connection (24, 0) 10.15.30.235:58444
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] accept_connection: 10.15.30.235:58444
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp:send_handler called to send to peer [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp:send_handler CONNECTING
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:tcp:complete_connect called for peer [[63716,0],0] on socket 19
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp_peer_complete_connect: sending ack to [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler called
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] RECV CONNECT ACK FROM UNKNOWN ON SOCKET 24
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] waiting for connect ack from UNKNOWN
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] connect ack received from UNKNOWN
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] connect-ack recvd from UNKNOWN
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] mca_oob_tcp_recv_connect: connection from new peer
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] connect-ack header from [[63716,0],1] is okay
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] waiting for connect ack from [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] connect ack received from [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] connect-ack version from [[63716,0],1] matches ours
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] tcp:peer_accept called for peer [[63716,0],1] in state UNKNOWN on socket 24
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] SEND CONNECT ACK
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] send blocking of 72 bytes to socket 24
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] blocking send complete to socket 24
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]-[[63716,0],1] tcp_peer_connected on socket 24
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]-[[63716,0],1] accepted: 10.15.30.222 - 10.15.30.235 nodelay 1 sndbuf 44800 rcvbuf 131072 flags 00000802
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] tcp:set_module called for peer [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] SEND CONNECT ACK
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] send blocking of 72 bytes to socket 19
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] blocking send complete to socket 19
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp_peer_complete_connect: setting read event on connection to [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:tcp:recv:handler called for peer [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] RECV CONNECT ACK FROM [[63716,0],0] ON SOCKET 19
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] waiting for connect ack from [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] connect ack received from [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] connect-ack recvd from [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] connect-ack header from [[63716,0],0] is okay
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] waiting for connect ack from [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] connect ack received from [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] connect-ack version from [[63716,0],0] matches ours
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]-[[63716,0],0] tcp_peer_connected on socket 19
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]-[[63716,0],0] connected: 10.15.30.235 - 10.15.30.222 nodelay 1 sndbuf 44800 rcvbuf 131072 flags 00000802
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler called for peer [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler CONNECTED
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler allocate new recv msg
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler read hdr
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler allocate data region of size 2743
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] RECVD COMPLETE MESSAGE FROM [[63716,0],1] (ORIGIN [[63716,0],1]) OF 2743 BYTES FOR DEST [[63716,0],0] TAG 10
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] DELIVERING TO RML tag = 10 seq_num = -1
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] OOB_SEND: rml_oob_send.c:265
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] oob:base:send to target [[63716,0],1] - attempt 0
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] oob:base:send known transport for peer [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] oob:tcp:send_nb to peer [[63716,0],1]:1 seq = -1
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:[oob_tcp.c:204] processing send to peer [[63716,0],1]:1 seq_num = -1 via [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] tcp:send_nb: already connected to [[63716,0],1] - queueing for send
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:[oob_tcp.c:218] queue send to [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] tcp:send_handler called to send to peer [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] tcp:send_handler SENDING TO [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] oob:tcp:send_handler SENDING MSG
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] MESSAGE SEND COMPLETE TO [[63716,0],1] OF 13 BYTES ON SOCKET 24
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:tcp:recv:handler starting send/recv events
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp:set_module called for peer [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp:send_handler called to send to peer [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp:send_handler SENDING TO [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] oob:tcp:send_handler SENDING MSG
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] MESSAGE SEND COMPLETE TO [[63716,0],0] OF 2743 BYTES ON SOCKET 19
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:tcp:recv:handler called for peer [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:tcp:recv:handler CONNECTED
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:tcp:recv:handler allocate new recv msg
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] OOB_SEND: rml_oob_send.c:265
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] oob:base:send to target [[63716,0],1] - attempt 0
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] oob:base:send known transport for peer [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] oob:tcp:send_nb to peer [[63716,0],1]:15 seq = -1
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:[oob_tcp.c:204] processing send to peer [[63716,0],1]:15 seq_num = -1 via [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] tcp:send_nb: already connected to [[63716,0],1] - queueing for send
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:[oob_tcp.c:218] queue send to [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] tcp:send_handler called to send to peer [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] tcp:send_handler SENDING TO [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] oob:tcp:send_handler SENDING MSG
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] MESSAGE SEND COMPLETE TO [[63716,0],1] OF 694 BYTES ON SOCKET 24
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:tcp:recv:handler read hdr
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:tcp:recv:handler allocate data region of size 13
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] RECVD COMPLETE MESSAGE FROM [[63716,0],0] (ORIGIN [[63716,0],0]) OF 13 BYTES FOR DEST [[63716,0],1] TAG 1
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] DELIVERING TO RML tag = 1 seq_num = -1
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:tcp:recv:handler called for peer [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:tcp:recv:handler CONNECTED
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:tcp:recv:handler allocate new recv msg
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:tcp:recv:handler read hdr
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:tcp:recv:handler allocate data region of size 694
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] RECVD COMPLETE MESSAGE FROM [[63716,0],0] (ORIGIN [[63716,0],0]) OF 694 BYTES FOR DEST [[63716,0],1] TAG 15
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] DELIVERING TO RML tag = 15 seq_num = -1
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] OOB_SEND: rml_oob_send.c:265
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:base:send to target [[63716,0],0] - attempt 0
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:base:send known transport for peer [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:tcp:send_nb to peer [[63716,0],0]:5 seq = -1
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:[oob_tcp.c:204] processing send to peer [[63716,0],0]:5 seq_num = -1 via [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp:send_nb: already connected to [[63716,0],0] - queueing for send
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:[oob_tcp.c:218] queue send to [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp:send_handler called to send to peer [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp:send_handler SENDING TO [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler called for peer [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler CONNECTED
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler allocate new recv msg
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler read hdr
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler allocate data region of size 54
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] RECVD COMPLETE MESSAGE FROM [[63716,0],1] (ORIGIN [[63716,0],1]) OF 54 BYTES FOR DEST [[63716,0],0] TAG 5
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] DELIVERING TO RML tag = 5 seq_num = -1
[cluster-01:06357] oob:tcp:send_handler SENDING MSG
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] MESSAGE SEND COMPLETE TO [[63716,0],0] OF 54 BYTES ON SOCKET 19
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler called for peer [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler CONNECTED
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler allocate new recv msg
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler read hdr
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler allocate data region of size 33
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] RECVD COMPLETE MESSAGE FROM [[63716,0],1] (ORIGIN [[63716,0],1]) OF 33 BYTES FOR DEST [[63716,0],0] TAG 2
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] DELIVERING TO RML tag = 2 seq_num = -1
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler called for peer [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler CONNECTED
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler allocate new recv msg
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler read hdr
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:tcp:recv:handler allocate data region of size 54
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] RECVD COMPLETE MESSAGE FROM [[63716,0],1] (ORIGIN [[63716,0],1]) OF 54 BYTES FOR DEST [[63716,0],0] TAG 5
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] DELIVERING TO RML tag = 5 seq_num = -1
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] OOB_SEND: rml_oob_send.c:265
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] oob:base:send to target [[63716,0],1] - attempt 0
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] oob:base:send known transport for peer [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] oob:tcp:send_nb to peer [[63716,0],1]:15 seq = -1
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:[oob_tcp.c:204] processing send to peer [[63716,0],1]:15 seq_num = -1 via [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] tcp:send_nb: already connected to [[63716,0],1] - queueing for send
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0]:[oob_tcp.c:218] queue send to [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] tcp:send_handler called to send to peer [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] tcp:send_handler SENDING TO [[63716,0],1]
[cluster-master:08881] oob:tcp:send_handler SENDING MSG
[cluster-master:08881] [[63716,0],0] MESSAGE SEND COMPLETE TO [[63716,0],1] OF 31 BYTES ON SOCKET 24
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] OOB_SEND: rml_oob_send.c:265
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:base:send to target [[63716,0],0] - attempt 0
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:base:send known transport for peer [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:tcp:send_nb to peer [[63716,0],0]:2 seq = -1
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:[oob_tcp.c:204] processing send to peer [[63716,0],0]:2 seq_num = -1 via [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp:send_nb: already connected to [[63716,0],0] - queueing for send
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:[oob_tcp.c:218] queue send to [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp:send_handler called to send to peer [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] tcp:send_handler SENDING TO [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] oob:tcp:send_handler SENDING MSG
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] MESSAGE SEND COMPLETE TO [[63716,0],0] OF 33 BYTES ON SOCKET 19
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] OOB_SEND: rml_oob_send.c:265
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:base:send to target [[63716,0],0] - attempt 0
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:base:send known transport for peer [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1] oob:tcp:send_nb to peer [[63716,0],0]:5 seq = -1
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0],1]:[oob_tcp.c:204] processing send to peer [[63716,0],0]:5 seq_num = -1 via [[63716,0],0]
[cluster-01:06357] [[63716,0]
```

Comment: I should note that I've tried googling the error. I've found a few different options, none of which seem to match my situation. Further, many were code errors in MPI or Slurm that are either long fixed or don't seem to affect my versions.

Comment: how did you install Open MPI? what if you `srun orted`? or `ssh cluster-01 orted` from `cluster-master`? what if you replace `mpirun` with the absolute path to `mpirun`?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, I've edited with that information. Hope it helps.

Comment: is there any firewall running on your nodes?

Comment: iptables exists but has empty chains defaulting to ACCEPT. I haven't installed anything else. It's the default non-gui install of raspbian. Both nodes are on wireless on the same AP. Soon they will be migrated to hard-wired ethernet to the same switch.

Comment: from `cluster-master`, and **not** within a `salloc`, try running `mpirun --host cluster-01 --mca oob_tcp_base_verbose 10  -n 1 hostname`

Comment: It hung for 5 minutes before I killed it.

Comment: any output before it hangs?

Comment: None. It makes debugging difficult.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229639/discussion-between-elros-and-gilles-gouaillardet).

Comment: What does `ifconfig -a` say on both hosts?

Comment: Added to the question. Nothing seems unusual or out of place on either one, other than that eth0 is up (though not connected). Any chance mpi is trying to bind to eth0 instead of using the wireless card?

Comment: it should not, try `mpirun --mca oob_tcp_if_include wlan0 ...` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I am sorry I made a typo earlier. To generate logs, try `mpirun --mca oob_base_verbose 10 ...`

Comment: Added the run with the fixed typo. The try with `--mca oob_tcp_if_include wlan0` didn't output anything and also hung.

Comment: you did check that from `cluster-master`, `ssh cluster-01 hostname` works correctly, right?

Comment: assuming it does, I am running out of ideas. Your best bet would be to rebuild Open MPI from source with `--enable-debug` so debug info can be generated and they will hopefully point to the root cause.

Comment: Yes, ssh works correctly, though it does require password. Do I need to setup passwordless logon (ssh keys) for this? I wouldn't have expected to as `srun` works just fine as is. Only MPI is having troubles.

Comment: Open MPI should use `srun` under the hood, but only when invoked from a SLURM allocation (e.g. `salloc` or `sbatch`). Assuming you ran `mpirun --host cluster-01 ...` from `cluster-master` **outside** of SLURM (at least for debugging purpose), then yes, you need to configure passwordless SSH.

Comment: Ok, that probably explains why my `mpirun` tests have been hanging entirely and not producing errors. Something underneath is sitting at the password prompt. When I have a chance, I'll fix that and re-run the tests.

It won't explain why a job queued with `sbatch` that calls `mpiexec` throws the original errors though, right?

Comment: In theory, `mpiexec` within a SLURM allocation such as `sbatch` should use `srun` instead of `ssh` in order to spawn the `orted` daemons. but let's make one step at a time ... maybe `ssh` will evidence something wrong with `orted`, or maybe `mpiexec` does not use `srun` as we would hope.

Comment: I've updated to include the now successful mpirun with the debugging output. Adding passwordless ssh fixed that. 

Running from within sbatch still produces the same error. I also tested doing `mpirun -n 4 hostname` which successfully prints the hostname 4 times on `cluster-master`. Increasing -n to more than 4 fails complaining of not enough slots though.

Comment: I should probably note that I'm not tied to using slurm if it's just causing more trouble. My intent is to be able to practice learning MPI and high-performance-computing methods without causing too much complication.

Comment: outside SLURM, I guess you want to `mpirun --host cluster-master:2,cluster-01:4 ...` so you can use 2+4=6 slots. You can also `mpirun --oversubscribe ...` to run more MPI tasks than slots.

Comment: Under SLURM, you can `mpirun --mca plm_base_verbose 10 ...` to generate some more logs. TL;DR it should use the `slurm` component (and show the `srun` command), **not** the `rsh` one.

Comment: All this for a permissions error. I got it all working outside of SLURM, which was probably good enough for my purposes. But after this work, I wanted SLURM working properly. Your last debugging command inside SLURM revealed that `/etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf` on cluster-01 was readable only by root and causing srun to fail when running as the `pi` user. Fixing the permissions appears to have kicked off the job.

Comment: If you care to summarize in an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks again for all your help. I'd never have gotten this working without it.

Comment: thanks for the offer! this is unlikely to help future readers, so I am gonna leave it like that.